# How to add first element of an array to first element of another array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the bellow [sic] two arrays:

```
first_name = ["prabhu" ,"raghu" , "satish"]
second_name = ["chaitanya", "varma", "venkey"]
```

I want to print the following output:

```
full_name = ["prabhu chaitanya","raghu varma", "satish venkey"]
```

Comment: If you can modify `second_name`, you could do this (but using `zip` is the obviously what you should be using): `first_name.map { |f| "#{f} #{second_name.shift}" }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
first_name.zip(second_name).map{ |x| x.join(' ')}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[first_name, second_name].transpose.map{|a| a.join(" ")}
```

Comment: I like this method. I tried with `zip` method not know with `transonse` can be possible. Sawa you are great. Your answers are always unique and let me learn new trick everytime. I m big fan of u ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also:

```
full_name = [];
first_name.each_with_index {|x, i|  x + second_name[i]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first_name.zip(second_name).map { |f, l| "#{f} #{l}" }
=> ["prabhu chaitanya", "raghu varma", "satish venkey"]
```

Alternatively:

```
first_name.zip([" "].cycle, second_name).map(&:join)
=> ["prabhu chaitanya", "raghu varma", "satish venkey"]
```